# How to run sh script in command task using ansible

Tags: command, sh, ansible

Ok.. Here I go. This is my main.yml content.

```
- hosts: web-servers
  tasks:
    - name: Run the below script
      command: sh temp/myscript.sh
```

I have a shell script named "myscript.sh" placed under a directory called 'temp'. My directory hierarchy is:

- ansible-copy-role (directory)

  - main.yml
  - temp  (directory)

    - myscript.sh  ( I want to run this Shell script)

I don't want to copy the shell script to my host servers and run from thre. I want to run the shell script which will be available along with the main.yml file.

When I run this playbook, I get an error like: **stderr: sh: temp/myscript.sh: No such file or directory**

Please help on this.

Answer (score 8):

If you keep this in mind you will find Ansible much simpler:

**Ansible modules run on the target host.**

If you do this:

```
- name: run some command
  command: foo
```

Then that task will try to run the command `foo` on the host *to which Ansible is connecting*, not on the host where you're running Ansible.

If you want to run a task locally, you need to be explicit about that.  For example:

```
- hosts: web-servers
  tasks:
    - name: Run the below script
      delegate_to: localhost
      command: sh temp/myscript.sh
```

This uses the `delegate_to` directive to have this task run on
`localhost` rather than on whichever `web-servers` host this task
would normally target.

See [the Ansible documentation on delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to @larsks fine answer, `local_action` is a shorthand to `delegate_to: localhost`. Therefore this could become:

```
- hosts: web-servers
  tasks:
    - name: Run the below script
      local_action: command sh temp/myscript.sh
```

Use the [same link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) as reference to this.